# Entity Framework GetValidationErrors empty for unique index

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, validation, entity-framework-6

I want to check for validation errors before I save the context.
I call context.GetValidationErrors(), which is empty, then I call context.SaveChanges() and I get the error for a duplicate row for my unique index.

```
using(var context = new DefaultDbContext())
{
    var user = new User()
    {
        OSIdentity = "test"
    };
    var duplicateUser = new User()
    {
        OSIdentity = "test"
    };
    context.Users.Add(user);
    context.Users.Add(duplicateUser);    
    // this is empty
    var errors = context.GetValidationErrors(); 
    if(errors.Count == 0)
    {
        // this throws the exception for duplicate row for unique index "Idx_UserOSIdentity"
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My User Entity has the following column:

```
[Index("idx_UserOSIdentity", IsUnique = true)]
[Display(Name = "OSIdentity")]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "...")]
[StringLength(450, ErrorMessage = "...")]
public string OSIdentity { get; set; }
```

Why is the unique index not checked when context.GetValidationErrors() is called, but is thrown afterwards on context.SaveChanges()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior as per EF architecture.

EF has four types of data validations;

`Data Annotations:` mainly for UI error check like `length`, `email format` etc, the `IndexAttribute` is not a validation attribute, it also doesn't have the `ErrorMessage` property, and it also doesn't have the `IsValid`() method that is used to validate it against a range of valid values. This is the reason `getValidationErrors` is not checking uniqueness.

`IValidatableObject`: Hook for more custom checks, by adding a 'validate'  method to do more complex check than can not be achieved with the data annotations

`ValidateEntity`: A `DbContext` method that allows access to the database 
for doing validation. In My view **here you can write you own logic to check the uniqueness before saving.**

**`DbUpdateException`:** Capturing `database-generated errors`, EF works on top of our database and database has its own data integrity,  after EF’s `SaveChanges()` or `SaveChangesAsync()` in case of database integrity failure **like your case of uniqueness failure** then the commit is rolled back and the errors are passed back via an exception.

**This is purely as per your choice, where do you want to catch/handle the database's data integrity exceptions.**

Comment: But the [Index] flag is in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace, so why isn´t it checked with the other Data Annotations?

Comment: The IndexAttribute is not a validation attribute, it also doesn't have the ErrorMessage property, and it also doesn't have the IsValid() method that is used to validate it against a range of valid values.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. So I guess for the Index attribute it is best to check duplicates before I add the Entity to the context.

Comment: yes, please mark as answered it helped and for others visitor also.